# What this person is saying in "American English" accent?

Tags: american-accent, dialect, understanding, accent

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6ILln2DQ84)

At 1:02: He says

> Human beings should be ..... from each other.

Also a little bit confusion between 0:02 and 0:10. I believe it is:

> Went through .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:02

> we believe human beings simply can't understand each other

0:02

> the two of us are both seeking the very same thing

Comment: So we believe *that*...